# Minimum rank of a (weakly) diagonally dominant matrix with non-zero rows?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix that is (weakly) [diagonally dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix), i.e., $|A_{ii}| \ge \sum_{j\ne i}|A_{ij}|$ holds for all $i \in [n]$. Furthermore, suppose that every row of $A$ is non-zero. What is the lowest possible value of $\mathrm{rank}(A)$ as a function of $n$?

It is easy to see that the answer is between $n / 4$ and $n / 2$. For the upper bound, simply consider the block diagonal matrix in which every block is a $2\times 2$ all-one matrix.

For the lower bound, consider the following probabilistic argument, a variant of which was used in [KQS23, Lemma 10] to prove a slightly more general result. Let $S \subseteq [n]$ be a random set that includes each $i \in [n]$ independently with probability $1/2$. Let $T \subseteq S$ be the set of indices $i \in S$ such that either: (1) $|A_{ii}| > \sum_{j\ne i}|A_{ij}|$; or: (2) $|A_{ii}| = \sum_{j\ne i}|A_{ij}|$ and there exists $j \in [n] \setminus S$ such that $A_{ij} \ne 0$.

It is easy to verify that: (1) for every $i \in [n]$, $\Pr[i \in T] \ge 1/4$; (2) the $|T| \times|T|$ sub-matrix of $A$ defined by $T$ is strictly diagonally dominant, and thus full-rank. By a probabilistic argument, there is a set $S$ such that $|T| \ge n / 4$, which implies $\mathrm{rank}(A) \ge n / 4$.

[KQS23] Weihao Kong, Mingda Qiao, Rajat Sen. A Combinatorial Approach to Robust PCA. https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.16416

Comment: It can be proved by mathematical induction that the minimum possible rank is $\lceil n/2\rceil$.